# integer to single precision conversion in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, casting, single-precision

I can't figure out how to convert an integer to a single precision using python, I already tried to use numpy but the float32() function doesn't help.

example
984761996 -> 1.360135E-3

Comment: Please add the code you have already tried so that we can see where you have gone wrong.

Answer (score 0):

this is the code I wrote:

```
import math
n = 984761996
size = 32

IEEE754 = {16: [5,15],32: [8,127],64: [11,1023],80: [15,16383],128: [15,16383]}

b = bin(n)
b = b[2:].zfill(size)
signal = b[0]
exponent = b[1:IEEE754[size][0]+1]
fraction = b[IEEE754[size][0]+1:]

i=-1
fraction_ten = 0
for c in fraction:
    fraction_ten = fraction_ten + int(c)*math.pow(2,i)
    i = i - 1

n_ten = math.pow(-1,int(signal)) * (1 + fraction_ten) * math.pow(2,(int(exponent,2)-IEEE754[size][1]))

print "%.6E" % n_ten
```